# cant get the value passed while creating object in constructor

Tags: java, exception, constructor

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Here I'm trying to throw custom exception if the `lastName` is empty/null, so I have created a constructor which accepts two string arguments and the value is passed while the object is created, but the problem is it's always null in the constructor. Seems like the value is not being passed. What am I doing wrong here? Any alternate solution or explain please. Thanks (Sorry for bad English).

```
public class Employee {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
        public Employee(String firstName,String lastName) {//here the value is always null and so throwing exception.
            try {
            if(this.firstName==null||this.lastName==null) {
                throw new FirstnameOrLastnameNotFound("Both first and last name must not be empty");    
            }   
            }
            catch(FirstnameOrLastnameNotFound e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                System.exit(1);
            }
            this.firstName=firstName;
            this.lastName=lastName;
        }
        public void display() {

            System.out.println("Name of the employee: " + this.firstName+" "+ this.lastName);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Enter the first name:");
        //String firstNameAndLastName=sc.nextLine();
        //String[]name=firstNameAndLastName.split(" ");
        Employee obj= new Employee("dummy", "dummy");//this dummy sting is not passing in constructor.
        obj.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of this  {if(this.firstName==null||this.lastName==null)} if i use  {if(firstName.length()==0||lastName.length()==0)} it works fine but i cant understand why!

Comment: take a look at shadowing in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are testing the value of the class members `firstName` and `lastName` **before** you are assigning them values.

You want to test whether the constructor *parameters* are null, so just remove `this.`.

Here is your corrected code.

```java
public class Employee {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName) {
        try {
            if (firstName == null || lastName == null) { // CHANGE HERE
                throw new FirstnameOrLastnameNotFound("Both first and last name must not be empty");
            }
        }
        catch (FirstnameOrLastnameNotFound e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Name of the employee: " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee obj = new Employee("dummy", "dummy");
        obj.display();
    }
}
```

You also wrote in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66914779/cant-get-the-value-passed-while-creating-object-in-constructor#comment118282694_66914779) that it works when you remove `this.`

Note though, that your fix will throw `NullPointerException` if you call the constructor with null argument, for example:

```java
Employee obj = new Employee(null, "dummy");
```

If null or empty names are not allowed, then your check should be as follows:

```java
if (firstName == null || firstName.isEmpty() || lastName == null || lastName.isEmpty()) {
    throw new FirstnameOrLastnameNotFound("Both first and last name must not be empty");
}
```

The idea behind throwing an [exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) is to indicate to the invoking code that the invoked method failed. You usually don't throw an exception **and** handle it in the same method. You should declare that the constructor throws `FirstnameOrLastnameNotFound` and put the `try-catch` in method `main` as below:

```java
public class Employee {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName) throws FirstnameOrLastnameNotFound {
        if (firstName == null || firstName.isEmpty() || lastName == null || lastName.isEmpty()) {
            throw new FirstnameOrLastnameNotFound("Both first and last name must not be empty");
        }
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Name of the employee: " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Employee obj = new Employee("dummy", "dummy");
            obj.display();
        }
        catch (FirstnameOrLastnameNotFound e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```